# Getting spikes in gRPC calls every hour

Tags: c#, go, grpc

I have a website running with around 7 servers (C#). And there is a gRPC service (golang) running with 3 instances. Each web server connects to and makes calls to the gRPC service. There are around 8000 calls per minute to the service.

The call to this service is not that critical, so lately we reduced the deadline of the call to 20 milliseconds. Here we noticed something strange. There was a spike in the "deadline exceeded" errors every hour throughout the day. And it happens exactly at 0th minute i.e. 2pm 3pm 4pm etc.

[image: spike in errors]

Why does this happen?

I came across [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1463) saying gRPC resets the connection every hour, but nothing more than that.

So my question is does gRPC internally refresh the connection every hour. If yes is there anyway to tweak this behavior. If no then can someone give some direction as to how I can debug why this is happening.

Comment: I'd suggest gathering, say, 30 seconds of runtime trace from one gRPC server instance so that it has 15 s before the alleged spike and 15 s after.
The trace can be obtained by doing something like `curl 'http://endpoint/debug/pprof/trace?seconds=30' >runtime.trace`
You can then analyze it for any anomalies like spikes in the GC.
On how to use the trace, see `go tool trace --help`.
Besides extracting pprof-ready stuff from it, the `-http` flag enables viewing the trace using the Chromium-s built-in visualizer.
See https://making.pusher.com/go-tool-trace/ for more info.

Comment: If the anomaly only appears exactly on the hour, and restarting it doesn't shift the spikes, It would make more sense to look for some external system factor, like a cron job that is taking too many resources. Though I don't know anything about the C# implementation, most systems add jitter to the deadlines to prevent spikes like these. If you're setting a 20ms deadline on the client, it's probably not long enough to cover when you need to make new connections.

Comment: @kostix I ran the trace as you suggested. I could not find any different behavior on the gRPC server. I also logged the time each call is taking on the server, all seems fine. I think I will look into what JimB suggested and look out for issues on the client side

Comment: @JimB you were right. There was a scheduled windows service that was running. And it was configured in a wrong way which caused hundreds of instances of the light job to run every hour. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, grpc-go does not refresh connections.  The only time it initiates a disconnect is if you configure "max idle" ([ref](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/keepalive#ServerParameters)) and the connection has been idle for longer than that time limit.  By default this is disabled, so it's unlikely to be the culprit in this case.

Comment: On the client side, another thing you can look at is the grpc debug logs, which should show when connections encounter errors.  (And if you're using a very recent version -- in the last week or two -- it now logs *all* connection state changes, regardless of cause.)